# SEO and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

I am building a web application with Angular JS, I need this to be fully SEO-optimized. 
It seems that for a few, google is able to crawl angular app but it is not clear if it can read everything (eg I read that directives cannot be interpreted).
So today, is an angular app fully google-compatible even if we use the full set of JS functions? What about other engines? Do we still need fantomJS static generation for Yahoo or microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, AngularJS is still not fully SEO-optimized. Thus, a lot of developers still find it necessary to use services like [Predender.io](https://prerender.io/) or cooking up their own implementation by using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Great strides have been made towards SEO-friendliness, especially when talking about AngularJS 2.0 since it allows you to render HTML on the server side ([More info here](https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-server-rendering)).

However, even with the new additions it's better to retain control over what the search engines are seeing by creating pre-rendered versions of your site.

Here is a great article about this very topic: https://builtvisible.com/javascript-framework-seo/

To quote some parts of it:

> Google can render and crawl JS sites. This, however is no guarantee that the outcome will be an SEO friendly, perfectly optimised site! Technical SEO expertise is needed, especially during testing. This will ensure that you have an SEO friendly site architecture, targeting the right keywords. A site that continues to rank despite the changes made in Google’s crawl.
>
> In my opinion, it’s better to retain tighter control of what’s being rendered by serving Google a pre-rendered, flat version of your site. This way, all the classic rules of SEO apply and it should be easier to detect and diagnose potential SEO issues during testing.

As far as other search engines, it seems like they currently don't support javascript rendering yet: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/webmaster-guidelines-30fba23a

> The technology used on your website can sometimes prevent Bingbot from being able to find your content.  Rich media (Flash, JavaScript, etc.) can lead to Bing not being able to crawl through navigation, or not see content embedded in a webpage.  To avoid any issue, you should consider implementing a down-level experience which includes the same content elements and links as your rich version does.  This will allow anyone (Bingbot) without rich media enabled to see and interact with your website.

Comment: Thanks for the links I also found ghostwriter.io. Does anyone has a feedback about static pages generated ? Is the result for same for google ? Will I not be penalized? I must be sure because I am building a public portal so without a good ranking in google it's not worth using angular

Comment: I've used Prerender.io with great results. The result in Google is the same as what users see, so all the SEO techniques apply. You don't necessarily have to use Prerender.io; you can roll up your own solution using Phantom.js etc.
I know that prerendering your content and then presenting that to the search engines works. That's your best bet.